Is MSE ok with how younger users may type?
I was just wondering if this website is tolerant towards the way younger people on this website may type (such as the use of slang) (assuming they are following the guidelines of course).

Relevant: Users must be at least 13.

I answered below. But I must say that if you are using slang, then you are in fact NOT following the MSE guidelines i.e., egregiously improper grammar and slang is itself a violation of the MSE guidelines.

Capitalize the first letter of the first word in a sentence.  (e.g. use I and not i, don't use "u" you express "you", don't use "ur" in stead of "you are", or "you're", etc., and I endorse the explanations given in the answers.

slang is very malleable and can change quickly, and creates problems in understanding. As this is meant to be, among other things, a repository of mathematical answers, anything that makes a post likely to be unintelligible in the future (even if it is more or less clear in the present) should be discouraged.

uggupuggu, Can you post some examples in your question? What exactly slang means is not clear to me.

@Srini Slang on Wikipedia.

To address a comment in your OP, I must say that if you are using slang in your posts on here, then you are in fact NOT following the MSE guidelines. Put another way, egregiously improper grammar and slang is itself a violation of the MSE guidelines.
So on that note, I admit to NOT being tolerant. I've even gone so far to downvote/vote-to-close questions, because of the bad grammar. I make no apologies for this, as in the long run it does everyone good.
When you apply for college you will be expected to use proper grammar and spelling. When you express interest in a technical position, bad grammar and incorrect spelling can greatly weaken and sink your application. So I am not alone in this regard.
Also, using slang, as I see it, shows disrespect to the rest of the community. It takes some effort to use proper grammar so as to fit in with the mores of the community and to not use it says that you couldn't be bothered to put in that effort. If you are still in high school and you want to participate in this adult space, please try to fit in.

To be clear I'm not talking about a stray typo or a minor grammatical or formatting error hidden in there somewhere. That happens to the best of us. I am talking instead about use of slang and/or a distinct lack of effort to use good grammar or punctuation.  And on that note, also a lack of effort to format the math properly too..

"to not use it says that you couldn't be bothered ...." Split infinitive! Split infinitive!

@GerryMyerson But the axiom of choice says it's fine to split infinitives! :P

No.  On Stack Exchange platforms, people are expected/encouraged to use proper English with proper punctuation, correct grammar, etc., and avoid slang, "txt-speak", unnecessary expletives, offensive language, overly colloquial language, salutations, etc.   Please avoid such informal style of communication.
If English is not your first language, do your best, and that is sufficient.
For more details, see the following resources:

How to deal with user using txt spk
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/781723
Should I clean up txt-msg speak in questions and answers?
Should leetspeak be edited out of posts?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375725/781723
Which common English language errors and idioms make SO questions tough to read?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273254/781723


@Srini, Done, thank you for highlighting that.  I didn't read carefully enough, thank you for calling that out.

No. What you type will be read by dozens, if not hundreds of other people, many for whom English is not their first language. They are spending their time and energy trying to make sense of what you have written.
So you should do your best to be as clear as possible. Skip the slang, don't reference memes, and don't worry about using the latest language. It would be rude to do otherwise.
(If it helps to put it this way: be basic, mid, demure, and completely Ohio.)

It hurts me to upvote something which encourages folks to emulate Ohio, but duty calls.

I vote for Wisconsin-ese in the Sourthern half of the state.

I don't even know why "Ohio" apparently means what it does. I'm just reporting what a friends kid explained to us this weekend :-): https://www.cincinnati.com/story/news/2024/08/22/what-is-ohio-rizz-why-insult-gen-alpha-slang-helpful-guide/74903138007/

High in the middle, round at both ends.
